# DBUnit, Hibernate/JPA, DAO and flush

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, dbunit

### Goal

In order to test the create method of a DAO, I create an instance, insert it in database, flush the entity manager to update the database and then use dbunit to compare table using dataset.

---

### Code

Here is the code, it uses Spring test, DBUnit and JPA (via Hibernate) :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "/WEB-INF/applicationContext-database.xml"})
public class MyEntityTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    MyEntityDAO myEntityDAO;

    @Test
    public void createTest() {
        // create the entity
        MyEntity record = new MyEntity();
        record.setData("test");    
        myEntityDAO.insertNew(record);

        // flush to update the database
        em.flush();         

        // get actual dataset from the connection
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        Connection conn = SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(
            session.getSessionFactory()).getConnection();
        DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(conn);
        ITable actualTable = connection.createTable("MY_ENTITY");

        // get expected dataset
        IDataSet expectedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(getClass().getResource("dataset.xml"));
        ITable expectedTable = expectedDataSet.getTable("MY_ENTITY");

        // compare the dataset
        Assertion.assertEquals(expectedTable, actualTable);
    }
}
```

---

### Problem

This code never ends, it seems to freeze (infinite loop ?) during this command:

```
ITable actualTable = connection.createTable("MY_ENTITY");
```

But if I comment the `em.flush()` block, the test ends (no freeze or infinite loop). In this case, the test fails because the database has not been updated after the insert.

---

### Question

how can I test the create method of a DAO using a similar approach (compare dataset with dbunit) without having a freeze when calling dataset.getTable() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was caused by the connection.

If I replace :

```
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
Connection conn = SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(
        session.getSessionFactory()).getConnection();
```

by

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) applicationContext.getBean("dataSource");
Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(ds);
```

All runs fine...

I don't understand why, so let me know in comments if you have any clue to help me understand that.